# Django admin site: how to change admin URL based on verbose_name

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

`class Meta: verbose_name` only changes its displayed name. But when its clicked. i want its url changed too based on verbose name

Here's my code:

Models:

```
tables = [f.id for f in StockId.objects.raw(
    "SELECT TABLE_NAME AS id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'my_project_auth_stockid%%'")]

table_map = {}
for tbl in tables:
    class Stocks(models.Model):
        user_id = models.IntegerField()
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        mrp = models.IntegerField()
        selling_price = models.IntegerField()


        class Meta:
            db_table = tbl
            managed = False
            verbose_name = _(tbl)
            verbose_name_plural = _(tbl)

    table_map[tbl] = Stocks
```

Admin.py

```
from my_project_auth.models import *

class AllStocksAdmin(AdminSite):
    site_header = 'All User Stocks'


stockadmin = AllStocksAdmin(name="stockadmin")

for tbl in tables:
    class StocksAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = StocksAdminResource
        list_display = ["product_name"]


    stockadmin.register(table_map[tbl], StocksAdmin)
```

What I am trying to do is in above to make multiple stock table out of single model. But Admin panel for each stocks is not working. All stocks table is pointing towards single table because of admin URL is based on model's class name.

I'm trying to do something like this in Admin.py, please suggest changes:

```
for tbl in tables:
    class StocksAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class = StocksAdminResource
        list_display = ["product_name"]


    def get_urls(self):                                                   # Not Working
        urls = super(StocksAdmin, self).get_urls()

        my_urls = path(f'stockadmin/{tbl}/', self.admin_view(stockadmin))

        return my_urls + urls
```

Comment: How many of these tables are there? You could create unique names for your models to get around this issue if you're not too attached to the way you have it now?

Comment: @IainShelvington every user will have there own stock table.. i can work around with present code logic but every user will have its own table is persistent

Comment: Do you have any say in the design of this solution? Having a table per user is going to surface more and more problems like this.

Comment: @IainShelvington  main logic of this project is that user will select  product from "master product table" and have there own stock table(for their own subdomain site) to sell.   yes there will be like 100s of 1000s of table but for now since its in initialize phase having admin panel its helps alot. Thanks for this solution man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem of having multiple models with the same name we can generate then dynamically with unique names using the three argument form of [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type)

```
from django.db import models

tables = [f.id for f in StockId.objects.raw(
    "SELECT TABLE_NAME AS id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'my_project_auth_stockid%%'")]


class StockBase(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mrp = models.IntegerField()
    selling_price = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


for tbl in tables:
    class Meta:
        db_table = tbl
        managed = False
        verbose_name = tbl
        verbose_name_plural = tbl
    locals()[f'Stocks{tbl}'] = type(f'Stocks{tbl}', (StockBase,), {'Meta': Meta, '__module__': StockBase.__module__})
```

This will result in multiple models with the same fields, from the base class, and all with unique names.

I used `__subclasses__` in the admin to get all the created models but it's pretty much the same, just register all the models.

```
from django.contrib import admin

from . import models


class StocksAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["product_name"]


for cls in models.StockBase.__subclasses__():
    admin.site.register(cls, StocksAdmin)
```

Now your admin should be full of tens/hundreds/thousands of duplicate but named slightly different models